# Unable to disable keyboard date change in MUI DatePicker API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, calendar

Link to CodeSandBox : codesandbox.io/s/dl5jft?file=/demo.tsx

I don't want users to Edit dates via keyboard, I want them to select dates from date picker modal, how to disable this?[image],

i used the ReadOnly prop but it is disabling date selection itself, please help when i did readOnly, it is disabling the whole input, which made me unable to open the modal to select the date

```
    <GlobalStyle />
      <CalendarContainer>
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
          <DatePicker
            value={calendarVal}
            onChange={(newValue) => {
              handleChange(newValue);
            }}
            disabled={disabled}
            inputFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading
                {...params}
                name={name}
                error={error}
                disabled={disabled}
              />
            )}
          />
        </LocalizationProvider>
      </CalendarContainer>
```

Comment: Could you share your code in codesandbox?

Comment: Hey @MajidM. here is https://codesandbox.io/s/dl5jft?file=/demo.tsx
i want to disable keyboard editing of the calendar
only modal picking should be allowed

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For preventing user keyboard actions, you can set the functionality of the `onKeyDown` event to `preventDefault` and assign it to `TextField`:

```
 const onKeyDown = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
 };

return (
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
  <Stack spacing={3}>
    <DesktopDatePicker
      label="Date desktop"
      inputFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField onKeyDown={onKeyDown} {...params} />
      )}
    />
)
```

[image: Edit MaterialUIPickers Material Demo (forked)]

Comment: Yes, its working fine

Answer (score 15):

For me, in latest @mui 5, the other solutions weren't working properly.
The only solution that worked for me is:

```
<DatePicker
    dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}
    renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
            {...params}
            inputProps={{...params.inputProps, readOnly: true}}
        />
    )}
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

I have done 2 things to solve this:

1- set render input TextField to `readOnly` => no typing

2- add sx of TextField `caretColor: 'transparent'` => hide the caret

```
<DatePicker
  renderInput={params => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            InputProps={{
              readOnly: true,
            sx={{
              "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
                caretColor: 'transparent'
              }
            }}
          />
        )}
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

For @mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.1.0":

```
<DatePicker      
    slotProps={{
        textField: {
            readOnly: true,
        },
    }}
/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

In the documenation for @mui/x-date-pickers 6.16 for slot https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/#slots you can read that field: Component used to enter the date with the keyboard. https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/#DatePicker-slots-field.

In my case where i want to disable keyboard input but still have datepicker valid. I added slotProps={{field:{readOnly:true}}

```
                  <DatePicker
                        label={label}
                        value={value}
                        onChange={onChange}
                        format="yyyy-MM-dd"
                        slotProps={{
                            field: {
                                readOnly: true
                            }
                        }}
                    />
```

Comment: works like charm!

Answer (score 0):

@mui/x-date-pickers 6 above, renderInput is deprecated

```
      const disableKeyboardEntry = (e: any) => {
         if (e?.preventDefault) { 
        e?.preventDefault();
        e?.stopPropagation();
    }
}

    <DatePicker 
         views={['year']}
         label={'From'}
         minDate={moment('1990', 'YYYY')}
         maxDate={moment().endOf('year')}
         slotProps={{ 
         textField: { 
         onBeforeInput: disableKeyboardEntry, 
           
        variant: 'standard' } 
      }}
      />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In MUI X v5, you can make the DatePicker field readonly (only allowed to select via the picker) as follows:

```
<DatePicker
    slotProps={{
        textField: {
            inputProps: { // not InputProps
                readOnly: true
            }
        }
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For future lost souls looking to do the same thing, I spent some time to make it work as (what appears to be) a single button with the right cursor and everything. I hate keyboard-editable dates, and I hate clickable items that have a text cursor!

```
const [datePickerOpen, setDatePickerOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
return (
  <DatePicker
    value={new Date()}
    sx={{
      input: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
      }
    }}
    open={datePickerOpen}
    onClose={() => setDatePickerOpen(false)}
    slotProps={{
      textField: {
        inputProps: { readOnly: true },
        onClick: () => {
          if (!datePickerOpen) {
            setDatePickerOpen(true);
          }
        }
      }
    }}
  />
);
```